# Como ler um arquivo que está dentro de um EAR

Tags: java, java-ee, classes

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de uma aplicação ear

- minhaAplicacao.ear

  - /META-INF/arquivo.properties
  - arquivo.war/WEB-INF/lib/minhaLib.jar/minhaClasse.java

Gostaria de, a partir da minhaClasse.java, recuperar o arquivo.properties

Já tentei:

getClass().getResource("/META-INF/arquivo.properties")
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/META-INF/arquivo.properties")
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("/META-INF/arquivo.properties")

Todos retornam null

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 0):

Tente desta forma:

```
URL url = SomeClassInEar.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/META-INF/arquivo.properties");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Então, eu não tenho nenhuma classe diretamente no EAR. A classe está dentro de uma lib dentro do war que está dentro do EAR. Essa sua solução corresponde ao meu segundo exemplo que não funcionou. A url retornada é nula. Mas obrigado de qualquer forma.